# Can I install tools made for Kali-Linux in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, kali-linux

Can I install some tools like The Lazy Script in Linux Mint?
Some sites suggest that I can' run tools made for Kali Linux in ubuntu based distros. Is there any workaround for that? 
[TheLazyscript in Github](https://github.com/arismelachroinos/lscript)

Comment: I think you can as both are debian based os.

Comment: Do you know how can I install The lazy script in Linux mint ? @baponkar

Answer (score 0):

You can open a terminal and type the commands provided on GitHub:

```bash
cd
apt-get update
git clone https://github.com/arismelachroinos/lscript.git
cd lscript
chmod +x install.sh
./install.sh
```

I cannot be sure if it will work in Linux Mint as the dependencies might not be all satisfied as they are in Kali. You can just try.

If it does not work, you can just remove the script as shown on GitHub:

```bash
cd /root/lscript
./uninstall.sh
rmdir -r /root/lscript
```

Comment: `ncurses-dev` and `gnome-terminal` are the only dependencies listed in `install.sh`.  I bet it'll probably be fine.

Comment: Error
```
there was an error creating the child element for this terminal.
Failed to execute child process “bash /root/lscript/install.sh” (No such file or directory)
```
@Stewart

Comment: When you install the script, can you try to launch install.sh with sudo ? i.e. `sudo ./install.sh` at last line.

Comment: I've tried that too but it doesn't seem to be working. @FloT

Comment: Can you see something in /root directory ? Was lscript directory successfully created ?